# Getting invalid runtime when publishing google app java web application

Tags: java, google-app-engine

Anyone know what is wrong?

See the Eclipse error log for more details
!STACK 0
com.google.appengine.tools.admin.AdminException: Unable to upload app: Error posting to URL: http://appengine.google.com/api/appversion/create?app_id=guest-book&version=1&
400 Bad Request
Invalid runtime specified.

```
at com.google.appengine.tools.admin.AppAdminImpl.update(AppAdminImpl.java:47)
at com.google.appengine.eclipse.core.proxy.AppEngineBridgeImpl.deploy(AppEngineBridgeImpl.java:203)
at com.google.appengine.eclipse.core.deploy.DeployProjectJob.runInWorkspace(DeployProjectJob.java:97)
at org.eclipse.core.internal.resources.InternalWorkspaceJob.run(InternalWorkspaceJob.java:38)
at org.eclipse.core.internal.jobs.Worker.run(Worker.java:55)
```

Caused by: java.io.IOException: Error posting to URL: http://appengine.google.com/api/appversion/create?app_id=guest-book&version=1&
400 Bad Request
Invalid runtime specified.

```
at com.google.appengine.tools.admin.ServerConnection.send(ServerConnection.java:114)
at com.google.appengine.tools.admin.ServerConnection.post(ServerConnection.java:66)
at com.google.appengine.tools.admin.AppVersionUpload.send(AppVersionUpload.java:345)
at com.google.appengine.tools.admin.AppVersionUpload.beginTransaction(AppVersionUpload.java:159)
at com.google.appengine.tools.admin.AppVersionUpload.doUpload(AppVersionUpload.java:68)
at com.google.appengine.tools.admin.AppAdminImpl.update(AppAdminImpl.java:41)
... 4 more
```

Answer (score 2):

do you get permission for java on google app engine? You get this error if java (i.e. the 'runtime') is not enabled. Currently the preview is limited to  10,000 users and others can apply but have to wait... check my blog post [Writing Java Hello World for Google app engine](http://www.vineetmanohar.com/2009/04/11/writing-java-hello-world-for-google-app-engine) for details.

Answer (score 1):

Could it be that you haven't defined the application name in your appengine-xml correctly?

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<appengine-web-app xmlns="http://appengine.google.com/ns/1.0">
    <application>abcdef</application>
    <version>1</version>
    ....
</appengine-web-app>
```

where you are trying to publish to http://abcdef.appspot.com

Answer (score 1):

http://code.google.com/appengine/kb/java.html#runtime

Answer (score 0):

Some people seem to be experiencing that. There is a [bug report](http://code.google.com/p/googleappengine/issues/detail?id=1213) that you might want to vote up.